# Python dir() equivalent in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python

What I loved about Python was that if you wanted to know something about a particular module, you could just go something like this:

```
dir(django.auth.models)
```

and it would give you all the things inside of `models`, is there something similar to this in JavaScript?

Comment: Here you go: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523747/equivalent-of-pythons-dir-in-javascript

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), e.g.:

```
> Object.keys(window)
["top", "window", "location", "external", "chrome", "Intl", "v8Intl", "document", "$", "jQuery", "MSIsPlayback", "i", "prepareEditor", "StackExchange", "scriptSrc", "careers_adurl", "careers_cssurl", "careers_leaderboardcssurl", "careers_companycssurl", "careers_adselector", "_gaq", "_qevents", "jQuery171008060155878774822", "__qc", "quantserve", "uh", "_gat", "gaGlobal", "gauth", "genuwine", "moveScroller", "styleCode", "sanitizeAndSplitTags", "initTagRenderer", "showFadingHelpText", "initFadingHelpText", "profileLink", "EventEmitter", "votesCast", "tagRendererRaw", "tagRenderer", "ytCinema", "IN_GLOBAL_SCOPE", "prettyPrintOne", "prettyPrint", "PR_SHOULD_USE_CONTINUATION", "PR", "Markdown", "apiCallbacks"]
```

Comment: Although `Object.keys()` behaves like `dir()` in that it returns they keys without values, it is much more common to use `console.log()`.

Answer (score 2):

I don´t know if doesn´t have this option in 2013, but today we have:

```
console.dir(variable)
```

ps: This answer is for those fall here after a googling 'python dir in javascript' (like me! by the way).

Answer (score 1):

If you do `console.log(variable)` in javascript, you'll see information about that variable in your browser's debugging console. If the variable is an object for example, you'll see it's attributes.